# Tomcat WebDAV force download

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8

I have a tomcat webserver with the WebDAV servlet deployed. I have multimedia files that are accessible via WebDAV and want to force them to be downloaded when accessed via a browser instead of allowing the browser to stream them from the server. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. I wrote a filter to send all requests to the WebDAV servlet unless it was a multimedia file chrome would attempt to play. In that instance the request would be sent to a custom servlet that would set the `Content-Disposition` header and then write the file data to `response.getOutputStream()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure Content-Disposition header field.

> If the disposition type matches "attachment" (case-insensitively), this indicates that the recipient should prompt the user to save the response locally, rather than process it normally (as per its media type).¶
>
> On the other hand, if it matches "inline" (case-insensitively), this implies default processing. Therefore, the disposition type "inline" is only useful when it is augmented with additional parameters, such as the filename (see below).

[Reference](http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc6266.html#disposition.type)

Comment: How would I do that with the WebDAV servlet? I know I could do `response.setHeader` from a jsp but that doesn't really help me.